# Material-ui getMuiTheme missing after upgrading from 0.9 to 1

Tags: material-ui

> Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/leongaban/projects/go/src/github.com/pizzahutdigital/mythor/node_modules/material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme.js'

Been using the theme, style and components from http://www.material-ui.com/#/ to build a app at the moment.

However I need the Grid component which doesn't exist in `0.9` but exists here in the `1.0 beta` https://material-ui-next.com/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `"material-grid": "^0.1.0"` and installed that.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-grid

Had to add this to `index.js`

`import 'material-grid/dist/css/material-grid.css';`

Had to make sure my webpack 3 rules where updated

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      test: /\.s?css/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader'
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)/,
      loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]'
    }
  ]
}
```

Now the grid will work:

```
<div>
  <Grid>
    <Cell col={12}><div className="box">12</div></Cell>
  </Grid>
  <Grid>
    <Cell col={4} tablet={2} ><div className="box">4-2</div></Cell>
    <Cell col={8} tablet={6} ><div className="box">8-6</div></Cell>
  </Grid>
  <Grid>
    <Cell col={1} tablet={8} phone={4}><div className="box">1-8-4</div></Cell>
    <Cell col={1} tablet={8} phone={4}><div className="box">1-8-4</div></Cell>
    <Cell col={1} tablet={4} phone={4}><div className="box">1-8-4</div></Cell>
    <Cell col={1} tablet={4} phone={4}><div className="box">1-8-4</div></Cell>
    <Cell col={1}><div className="box">1</div></Cell>
    <Cell col={1}><div className="box">1</div></Cell>
    <Cell col={1}><div className="box">1</div></Cell>
    <Cell col={1}><div className="box">1</div></Cell>
    <Cell col={1}><div className="box">1</div></Cell>
    <Cell col={1}><div className="box">1</div></Cell>
    <Cell col={1}><div className="box">1</div></Cell>
    <Cell col={1}><div className="box">1</div></Cell>
  </Grid>
</div>
```

### Update for Ted

---

**The following throws an error:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
import * as Colors from 'material-ui/styles/colors';
import { fade } from 'material-ui/utils/colorManipulator';

// Styles
import 'material-grid/dist/css/material-grid.css';
import './styles/main.scss';

// Containers
import App from './containers/App';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  appBar: {
    color: Colors.cyan400,
    textColor: Colors.white
  },
  palette: {
    primary1Color: Colors.cyan500,
    primary2Color: Colors.blueGrey700,
    accent1Color: Colors.deepOrange500,
    accent2Color: Colors.blueGrey400,
    accent3Color: Colors.blueGrey500
  },
  cardMedia: {
    overlayContentBackground: fade(Colors.darkBlack, 0.87)
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <App />
  </MuiThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

> index.js:35 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _styles.createMuiTheme) is not a function

Answer (score 7):

`getMuiTheme` has been replaced by `createMuiTheme` in `'material-ui/styles'`

This worked for me : `import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';`

See Documentation -> https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/docs/src/pages/customization/themes.md

(Docs on `master` and `v1-beta` differ, be sure to check out the v1 branch docs)

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting this error when I switched over to that, I'll update my question above with the new code I added: ` index.js:35 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _styles.createMuiTheme) is not a function`

Comment: Ah, createMuiTheme doesn't exist... I upgraded Material-ui and only getMuiTheme is there